# Show list of registered users base on current month using laravel

Tags: laravel

Im new to laravel and im tryin to learn the fundamentals of it. My question is how can I display all the registered users that is registered only on the current month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$from = now()->startOfMonth(); // first date of the current month
$to = now();
$usersRegisteredThisMonth = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way of doing it.

Just use this code

```
User::whereMonth('created_at', now()->month) // checking if the month of created_at is current month
->whereYear('created_at', now()->year) // checking if the year of created_at is current year
->get();
```

This line will give you Users from current month.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody explained that these queries might be put in user model with local scope scopeWith magic method. I assume you read docs from top to bottom.

Simple example:

`public function scopeRegisteredLastMonth($query){ return $query->whereBetween... }`

[Laravel Local Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

You can specyficy additional arguments for this method.

The final call in controller will look like this:

```
$lastMonthUsers = User::registeredLastMonth()->get();
```

This function should be set to something like 'public function withRegisteredBetween($query, $date_start, $date_end) and return query based on date range.

PS: Don't use DB:: when you can use Model::method() or Model::query()->method()

PS2: for date management I advise you to install carbon, it's an additional addon - sometimes it's easy, sometimes not, overall not bad.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `users` table with a `whereBetween` clause like this:

```
$from = date('2022-01-05 00:00:00');
$to = date('2022-31-05 00:00:00');

$usersRegisteredThisMonth = DB::table('users')->
                whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```